# How to use sed substitution to return the value in JSON key:value pair?

Tags: json, variables, sed, substitution

How do I get the value "GET" only?

```
$ echo '"parameters":[],"method":"GET","uri":"example.com/abc/def/"' | sed 's/\"method\":\(.*\)\,/\1/'
```

This removes *"method":* but I need the key/value pair of *parameters* and *uri* removed, as well. Here's the result as it is

```
"parameters":[],"GET""uri":"example.com/abc/def/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have figured it out.

```
$ echo '"parameters":[],"method":"GET","uri":"example.com/abc/def/"' | sed 's/^.*\"method\":\(.*\)\,.*$/\1/g
```

Please feel free to suggest better answers.